# How to change attributes in fo:* elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I would like to transform a xml file into a xsl-fo to produce a pdf file. My problem is that some attributes are to be taken from the input xml, for example:

```
 <page width="210mm" height="297mm" />
```

and I would like to put with and height attributes inside:
    
in place of page-width and page-height attributes value. I tried unsuccesfully some ways, using a xsl variable:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster"
page-height="$height" page-width="$with" margin="2cm">
```

or xsl:value-of

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster"
page-height=<xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
page-width=<xsl:value-of select="$with"/> margin="2cm">
```

None of the above achieve any result as transform process stops with an error indicating some kind of sintax error.
What's wrong? How can I do?

Comment: <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster"
page-height="$height" page-width="$width" margin="2cm"> is not going to work on its own. You have to declare the variable and give it a value first. Did you do that?

Comment: @hobbes In my mind that should be obvious, as i said 'using a xsl variable'. By the way, yes I did but I used the wrong sintax. As you can see in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use attribute value templates https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-value-templates to compute values of literal result elements from XPath expressions (like a variable reference): `<fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster"
page-height="{$height}" page-width="{$with}" margin="2cm">`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with code like the following example:

```
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster" margin="2cm">
      <xsl:attribute name="page-width">
        <xsl:value-of select="$width"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="page-height">
        <xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
```

Comment: thank you for the soon reply. Can you explain what's <Output> tag? Did you mean <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster"><xsl:attribute name="page-height">
    <xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
  </xsl:attribute></fo:simple-page-master>

Comment: I've updated my example to a more clear one for your case in particular

Comment: In your example you are using $width and $height which would do nothing. If the user had those things in variables you would need {$width} and {$height}. If the user is looking for them within a template match for page, they could just use @ width and @ height and not any variable.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code (both the sample XML and the XSL you have written so far), it is not easy to guess. You give no context in which you would be creating the page-masters.

Let's assume your root element is `<document>` and the `<page>` element is a child of that element and you have only one `<page>` element. Like this:

```
<document>
   <page width="210mm" height="297mm" />
   <!-- more things here -->
</document>
```

Then in your XSL, you could grab those value in several ways:

**Option 1: Just use the attribute**

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster" page-height="{page/@height}" page-width="{page/@width}">
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageMaster">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Option 2: Use variables**

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="page/@width"/>
    <xsl:variable name="height" select="page/@height"/>
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster" page-height="{$height}" page-width="{$width}">
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageMaster">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Option 3: Use attribute template with the attribute directly**

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster">
                <xsl:attribute name="page-width">
                    <xsl:value-of select="page/@width"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="page-height">
                    <xsl:value-of select="page/@height"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageMaster">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Option 4: Use attribute templates with variables**

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="page/@width"/>
    <xsl:variable name="height" select="page/@height"/>
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster">
                <xsl:attribute name="page-width">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$width"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="page-height">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageMaster">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you may actually want the values of width and height for other reasons, maybe outside of this template in some other one. Assuming you have only one `<page>` element, then you could do this where the variables would be available throughout the whole XSL by defining them at the root before any templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="/document/page/@width"/>
    <xsl:variable name="height" select="/document/page/@height"/>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageMaster" page-height="{$height}" page-width="{$width}">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageMaster">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```